# Compiling Angular 2 as commonjs

Tags: angular, typescript, commonjs

I want to compile Angular 2 project as `commonjs` module.

I have this `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true
  }
}
```

I use `ntsc` and I got these kind of errors:

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(46,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(44,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts(32,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts(44,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
```

I have `npm` version `4.0.5`, `node` `v7.3.0` and `ntsc` `Version 2.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transpiling to es5 you have to add the following reference in your main ts file:

`///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`

Comment: I am having a similar issue with an Angular-CLI generated project. I am using Eclipse and the plugins from [Angelo Zerr](https://github.com/angelozerr). The "ng build" and "ng serve" commands work perfectly, but tsc shows me errors under node_modules. The path in your solution (node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts) does not exist, it is the old path from angular2 beta. How can i solve this in current Angular version?

Answer (score 1):

You want `target: "es6"`, those missing classes are not available in ECMAScript 5

Comment: But if I use `"es6"` as `target`, I also have to compile from ES6 to ES5

Comment: I don't know how es 6 code will get transpiled to es 5 and still works. But if you want to use es6 features in es5 code, you should check out babel which lets you do that

Comment: I followed this article: http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/